# r find one-to-one linkage between 2 cols

Tags: r, many-to-many, dataframe, one-to-one

I have a dataframe like this

```
df <- data.frame(g1=c("x1","x2","x2","x3","x4"),
                 g2=c("y1","y1","y2","y3",NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Each row indicates a certain x is linked to a certain y of the same row.

How shall I find how many x and y are uniquely linked, not counting na?

Like in this case, only 1 unique linkage x3 to y3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question, you're looking for the rows of your data frame where the `g1` value and the `g2` value are both unique. You can check for unique values in R with the `duplicated` function:

```
subset(df, !duplicated(g1) & !duplicated(g1, fromLast=TRUE) & !is.na(g1) &
           !duplicated(g2) & !duplicated(g2, fromLast=TRUE) & !is.na(g2))
#   g1 g2
# 4 x3 y3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the pairings with `table()`

```
tt <- do.call(table, Df)
```

and then find those cells with a match that have zeros in the rest of the cells in the shared row/column

```
uv <- arrayInd(which(rowSums(tt)[row(tt)] == 1 & colSums(tt)[col(tt)]==1 & tt>0), .dim=dim(tt))
```

Now extract the names of those cell

```
cbind(rownames(tt)[uv[,1]], colnames(tt)[uv[,2]])

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x3" "y3"
```

so here we get the x3,y3 pairing you desired form your sample

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use `igraph`. If in a graph `x` and `y` are uniquely linked, they will not be connected to any other nodes - so the graph will have `clusters`. So aim is to identify cluters of size two and extract the node names.

```
# extend your data a little to include another unique link
df <- data.frame(g1=c("x1","x2","x2","x3","x4","x7"),
                 g2=c("y1","y1","y2","y3",NA, "y8"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(na.omit(df[,1:2]))

plot(g) 

by(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership, as.character) [clusters(g)$csize==2]
#$`2`
#[1] "x3" "y3"

#$`3`
#[1] "x7" "y8"
```

**EDIT** Follow up to comment

You can assign colours (and other attributes) to the nodes using V(g)$color. You can assign these conditionally.

So to colour the nodes with a single link differently

```
b <- by(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership, as.character) [clusters(g)$csize==2]

V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$name %in% unlist(b), "red", "blue")

plot(g)
```

Or to colour each cluster differently

```
V(g)$color <- c("red", "blue", "green")[clusters(g)$membership]

plot(g)
```

Have a look at `?V`, `?clusters` and `?plot.igraph` for more options

Comment: This is very interesting. Is there a way to also apply a different color to those one-to-one pairs, either the vertice filling or border? Thank you@user20650

Comment: @santoku; your welcome. Please see edit re the colouring of nodes

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, but this works.

```
Df[sapply(Df2[,1], function(x) (sum(x == (d <- sapply(Df, substring, first = 2))[,2], na.rm=T)==1)&(sum(x == d[,1], na.rm=T)==1)),]
> g1 g2
  x3 y3
```